# Component with same UI but different data coming from redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Got a component but with different data coming from redux store, the UI is the same just change where data come from I use useSelector, so I'm passing selector through props.

- My first question is pass selector through props is fine or it's a bad practice?
- Second question is I got a type error and I don't know how I should type this correctly

```
Argument of type 'OutputSelector<MergeStateI, GrocerieResponse[], (res: GroceriesInitStateI) => GrocerieResponse[]> | OutputSelector<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: MergeStateI) => GrocerieResponse[]'.
  Type 'OutputSelector<MergeStateI, AgencyResponse[], (res: AgenciesInitStateI) => AgencyResponse[]>' is not assignable to type '(state: MergeStateI) => GrocerieResponse[]'.
    Type 'AgencyResponse[]' is not assignable to type 'GrocerieResponse[]'.
      Property 'grocerieImages' is missing in type 'AgencyResponse' but required in type 'GrocerieResponse'.
```

Selectors

```
export const selectFavoriteGroceries = createSelector(
    [selectGroceries],
    (groceries: GroceriesInitStateI) => groceries.favoriteGroceries
);

export const selectFavoriteAgencies = createSelector(
    [selectAgencies],
    (agencies: AgenciesInitStateI) => agencies.favoriteAgencies
);
```

Component

```
interface ComponentProps {
    selector:
        | OutputSelector<
              MergeStateI,
              GrocerieResponse[],
              (res: GroceriesInitStateI) => GrocerieResponse[]
          >
        | OutputSelector<
              MergeStateI,
              AgencyResponse[],
              (res: AgenciesInitStateI) => AgencyResponse[]
          >;
}

export const Restaurant: React.FC<RestaurantProps> = (
    props: RestaurantProps
) => {
    const data = useSelector(props.selector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass the selector function via props, I would just select the data in the parent component, and pass that data as a prop instead.